# Notation for $\max\{\,|z|\mid z\in\Bbb C\land f(z)=0\,\}$

Tags: notation, terminology

Let $f\in \Bbb C[X]$ be a non-constant polynomial. Then we can define

- The maximal absolute value of a root of $f$
- The smallest radius of a closed disk around the origin that contains all roots of $f$
- The reciprocal of the radius of convergence of the Taylor series for $\frac1{f(\frac1z)}$ around $0$
- ...

But I wonder: Is there no established shorter name for the concept? I was about to try *root radius*, but that is something totally different.

Also: Is there a somewhat established notation? Something like $R(f)$ or $\operatorname{maxabs} f$ perhaps? Of course, there's always $\max f^{-1}(\{0\})$, but perhaps there's something else established ...

I found many texts that for example prove upper bounds for the (the thing), but none I found seems to bother giving a name or symbol to the exact value of (the thing) ...